# Chef Template If Else

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to dynamic change create a nginx xonfig file with chef using an erb. What is the correct syntax for if else it an .erb file.

The below code gives me an error

> (erubis):17: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting keyword_end

```
<% node['dd']['pipeline']['env'] -%>
resolver <%if node['dd']['pipeline']['env'] == "production" then 10.100.0.5 else 10.0.0.5 end -%> valid=30s;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `10.100.0.5` isn't a valid Ruby literal. You want this:

```
<%= if node['dd']['pipeline']['env'] == "production" then "10.100.0.5" else "10.0.0.5" end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. node['dd']['pipeline']['env'] doesn't appear to have any value when in the template. Am I mistaken on how I should be using this. It's definitely set in the recipe. I can output the data to stout. `16-Mar-2018 11:51:37     amazon-ebs: env = dev`

Comment: How are you setting it?

Comment: I'm using chef_gem 'java-properties' in the recipe to set the attribute

Comment: Not sure what you mean, a resource wouldn't set anything.

Comment: I thought of that after I boarded my plane yesterday. chef_gem 'java-properties' is used to create a hash updated_properties then node data is set using node.default['dd']['pipeline']['env']= updated_properties

Comment: It’s hard to say without seeing the code but either things are being overridden at a higher precedence level or it is being set after the template evaluates.